# jQuery animation - making an image visible from left to right

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make an image hidden hidden using jQuery. I am using `.hide()` function. I am applying it to div containing the image which has to be hidden.
Its not working for some reason. I have [created a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyfrancisjoseph/rAqcP/15/).

Is it possible to use `animate` so that the image becomes visible from right to left in say 1 sec. In other words, animate the width from 0 to maximum value but the image should become visible from left to right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were not using the correct syntax.missing ); at the end of each function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#animate').click(function() {
      $('#myimage').animate({width: 'hide'},1000);
   });  
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyfrancisjoseph/rAqcP/34/

Please see this fiddle. I want the animation to happen from right to left.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the working jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YBtbk/).

Couple of points:

- In your original fiddle, you forgot to use the terminating `)` - that's why the hiding did not work.
- To accomplish the animation, I've used the [blind](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Blind) jQuery easing. To use this (and other easings), you need to reference the jQuery UI library (as I am doing in the fiddle). Took me a while to figure out why the effect does not work till I ticked that little checkbox on the left :)

Just for the record, I am also posting the code from the fiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#animate').click(function() {
      $('#myimage').toggle('blind', { direction: 'horizontal' }, 1000);
   });  
});
```

Comment: Could you show me how hide the image on page load and then animate from left to right on a button press. Thats my exact requirement.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyfrancisjoseph/rAqcP/34/

Please see this fiddle. I want the anmimation to happen from right to left.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want :

http://jsfiddle.net/rAqcP/27/

Please change the animations as you need.

~K

Comment: Could you show me how hide the image on page load and then animate from left to right on a button press. Thats my exact requirement. What I need to animate is the visbility and not the x- position –

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyfrancisjoseph/rAqcP/34/

Please see this fiddle. I want the anmimation to happen from right to left.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should animate the width because the image will look weird when resized.

You can achieve what you want like this:

- set the container (the DIV#myimage) to `overflow: hidden` and `position: relative`: hiding the overflow will allow to move the image to the left *out of the container*
- set the image to `position: absolute` and move the image to the left to *hide* it
- animate the `left` property back to zero

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/MZfj9/)**

**[DEMO (initial state with css)](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/VjSNf/)**

Comment: Could you show me how hide the image on page load and then animate from left to right on a button press. Thats my exact requirement. What I need to animate is the visbility and not the x- position

Comment: I've changed the fiddle. Just set the `left` property of the image on domready instead of in the click event. You could also set it directly in the CSS (not by javascript) if you know the size of the image.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyfrancisjoseph/rAqcP/34/

Please see this fiddle. I want the anmimation to happen from right to left.